# Having a second document root server folder in Apache on El Capitan: access is forbidden

Tags: apache, terminal, apache2, osx-elcapitan, document-root

I want to define a second document root server folder in Apache2 in El Capitan 10.11.4. I could do that but it says access is forbidden. I tried these options:

- I added this snippet to my username.conf

```html
 <Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
       AllowOverride All
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

- I changed the permission over the username.conf by

```html
sudo chmod 644 username.conf
```

- I uncommented these lines in Httpd.conf

```html
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

However, I commented these lines out with #:

```html
<Directory />
221     AllowOverride none
222     Require all denied
223 </Directory>
```

I also uncommented this line:

```html
 LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

Also in httpd-userdir.conf I uncommented

```html
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

But still it says access if forbidden! I was wondering if anyone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I was missing the Sites folder in my user home directory, I created that and then created a sample folder and index page and that fixed it for me.